# HttpAuthorizer() for Pusher

Tags: android, authentication, pusher

I need a private channel on Pusher in order to enable a bunch of Android clients to communication with each other. Pusher was recommended to me, although it is *really* complicated. I've read all the docs many times, so I'm hoping someone (Mr. Leggetter?) could give me a hand.

I've installed the Pusher Android JAR on the client and am able to subscribe to public channels that I trigger from the "Event Creator" (very neat), but in order to get the private channel working, in order to trigger events, I need this:

```
HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer("http://example.com/some_auth_endpoint");
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setAuthorizer(authorizer);
Pusher pusher = new Pusher( YOUR_APP_KEY, options );
```

According to http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users, the HttpAuthorizer() needs a URL that points to an app server that is going to respond with a JSON authentication token. Do I have to set up my own app server to provide authentication, like the example at https://raw.github.com/pusher/pusher-android-example/master/src/com/pusher/android/example/MainActivity.java, or can Pusher provide this? This seems like something Pusher should provide.

In the Ruby server code example for my app (why is there no Java?) I see this: `Pusher.url = "http://{key}:{secret}@api.pusherapp.com/apps/{app_id}"`. This URL, however, does not exist. I tried it in HttpAuthorizer() and got a java.io.FileNotFoundException. (I just found the "Enable Clients Events" checkbox under Settings - checking it did not help, but I'm guessing that's an important step.)

If I have to set up my own app server for authentication, I'd like to use Java with GAE. http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_private_endpoints has a Python/GAE example, but no Java, and I don't know Python. Is there a library for this? Will https://github.com/marcbaechinger/gae-java-libpusher# do the trick? It doesn't seem like it would.

Comment: It's @leggetter :-) you should use the Pusher version, but your questions are still valid. Will answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> token. Do I have to set up my own app server to provide authentication, like the example at https://raw.github.com/pusher/pusher-android-example/master/src/com/pusher/android/example/MainActivity.java, or can Pusher provide this?

You need to set up your own authentication server. The point in this is to allow **you** to authenticate subscriptions. This means you can authenticate the user in any way you see fit, against any existing or new authentication mechanism you may use e.g. user sessions (more applicable to web apps) or authentication tokens your own application may provide upon initial connection (via some username/password login to your system).

> In the Ruby server code example for my app (why is there no Java?) I see this: Pusher.url = "http://{key}:{secret}@api.pusherapp.com/apps/{app_id}". This URL, however, does not exist.

There is a Java server library but Pusher don't directly maintain that. It's a community contributed one.

I'm not sure where you got the URL from. Maybe from the [Web API](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api) reference, but unless you are writing your own Pusher Web API library I wouldn't expect you to be using that URL directly. There are Pusher and contributed helper libraries for that sort of thing.

> If I have to set up my own app server for authentication, I'd like to use Java with GAE. http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_private_endpoints has a Python/GAE example, but no Java, and I don't know Python. Is there a library for this? Will https://github.com/marcbaechinger/gae-java-libpusher# do the trick?

Yes, you need to set up your own authentication server. You could create a client-side authorizer, but that would mean exposing your `app_secret` in client code - which you shouldn't do.

The [`PusherUtil`](https://github.com/marcbaechinger/gae-java-libpusher/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/mbae/pusher/util/PusherUtil.java#L27) class provides a number of helper methods that you could use to add subscription authentication support to the library. But - you are right - it doesn't appear to offer this functionality.

The Pusher Play module (also Java) does appear to have an appropriate method so this could be ported. See:
https://github.com/regisbamba/Play-Pusher#generating-the-authentication-string

I don't work for Pusher any more, but I would be happy to contribute to an improved Java library.

Comment: Thank you, @leggetter! I knew you'd have the answers and I appreciate the time you spent responding. This is, unfortunately, looking like a huge pain. Perhaps this is inappropriate to ask (not sure if Stack Overflow is the right place), but what do you think of https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/android? It looks like the Android client can easily publish and receive, and it looks like they have a Java server library as well, should I ever decide to do something with that. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies for misspelling your name.

Comment: You may ignore my question about PubNub. Should have checked out http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-competitive-advantages-of-Pusher-vs-PubNub first. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkCramer Setting up an auth server takes minutes - but I appreciate the lack of a Java example doesn't help you. For testing you could use [this python one](https://github.com/leggetter/pusher-examples/blob/master/python-gae/src/pusher_auth.py). I do think Pusher should have a setting in the dashboard that disables authentication for an application, but also restricts the app somehow to ensure you don't move it into production. PubNub is a great service, but I personally don't like the way their API handles security. You shouldn't embed a `PUBLISH_KEY` in a client IMHO.

Comment: @MarkCramer Jeremy's answer on Quora is outdated. Pusher does provide HTTP fallback for their JavaScript library. But other libraries, such as the Java one don't provide that fallback.

Comment: Setting up an auth server might take minutes for someone who knows what they're doing, but it'd probably take me weeks to figure it out. Thank you for the python example, but I have no idea how I would get that onto GAE. I believe Eclipse has a python plug-in, but thinking about trying to get that to work is depressing. It does seem like Pusher might be more secure, but at this point I'll take easy over safe since there's no point in being safe if I can never get it to work. ;-) Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @MarkCramer I don't think doing [these 7 steps](https://github.com/leggetter/pusher-examples/tree/master/python-gae#add-the-app-to-the-googleappenginelauncher) to get the auth server working in GAE would take you weeks :) No IDE required. Good luck with whatever solution you go with.